# Mongodb multiple fields equality check

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

```
 public long DebitLedgerBalance(string drLedgerId, string transactionId, decimal amount, string userID)
 {
        var filter = Builders<Transaction>.Filter.Eq(x => x._id, transactionId);
        UpdateDefinition<Transaction> update;
        update = Builders<Transaction>.Update.Inc(x => x.debitLedgerBalance, amount * -1);
     return db.Transaction.UpdateOne(x => x._id == transactionId, update).ModifiedCount;
 }
```

i'm using mongodb driver(v2.11.3) in asp.net core(v3.1) application.
In the code i'm checking equality of transactionId.I also want to check drLederId.
in short i need to check drledgerId and transactionId both.because I want to find a transaction from the database whose `_id`  is transactionId and a `ledgerId` is drledgerId.and if that found then update balance with use `Inc`.
so how can i check both fields at a time?

Comment: Can you post code as text instead of an image.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AnuragWagh Edited question with code